# Regular payment in Paypal using billing plans

Tags: paypal, payment

I would like to ask you about regular payment in paypal using billing plans. I use the PHP library from paypal (REST API) to create billing plans and agreement for users but I have some problems:

- I have two plans: STANDARD and PRO. What when the user buys a standard plan and after some time will be want to switch to another? What with the old subscription? I don't see the option to cancel subscription via REST API. Should I create a personal billing plan for every user and in this case update this changes?
- My plans include some additional parameters like: ,,How many people can use one account" - and this parameter influences on the final price. I don't know what I should do to get regular payments with flexible parameters. 
  Should I create a billing plan for every user and then create an agreement for this personal billing plan? What if user paid for 12 months and after 9 months will want to change some parameters - then I should upgrade price in the billing price (for stability in the next billing cycle) and to get this difference in plan costs I should create the normal payment by http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html?

Cheers!